# Degrees of Criticality / Lateness or whatever

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, technical, technology

I am writing a Web Application where I am going to list certain events and their overdue days. If an event is overdue by less than 10 days then its `safe`. If it is overdue by over 10 days but less than 30 days then I would add a flag called `warning` beside it.

The problem is I am not sure if the words `safe` and `warning` are proper.

Ok. The application is a timesheet application and I am listing the weeks where the User has not submitted the timsheets (timesheets are pending) and hence over due.

Can anyone give me 4 or 5 words to describe various degrees of overdue?

I am not sure how to word this question or do a Google search. What do you call these kind of set of words?

**EDIT:** 
I think Ive got answer for my question. But what do you call these series of words?

Comment: The *safe* category could be called a *grace period*.

Comment: Alert levels of *anything* can be named after respective colors: ... Alert: Amber! Alert: Orange! Alert: Red! (Green is not an alert level)

Answer (score 1):

I have recently addressed this problem in my own UX testing.

My research finds that people *need* a clear indicator of the time-scales related to each label.

That legend:

- can be always-visible in a legend on the side.
- can be introduced once, at the beginning of account use, in an 'orientation' process.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

late, very late, extremely late, unacceptably late

important, urgent, severely urgent, critically urgent

since you are building a web application you could also use a colour coding system on text or icons such as `green -> yellow -> orange -> red`

Comment: Great. Thank you. But I have decided to dump words and resorted to just colors :). Thanks a lot anyway.